# How do I save each iteration of a for loop in one big DataFrame - Python

Tags: python, dataframe, api, for-loop, stock

I want to gather all the historical prices of each stock in the S&P500 in Python. I'm using a package from IEX Cloud which gives me the historical prices of an individual stock. I want a for loop to run through a list of the tickers/symbols from the stock index so that I get all the data in a single DataFrame.

This is the code that produces a DataFrame - in this example I've chosen AAPL for a two year period:

```
import pyEX as p
sym = 'AAPL'
stock_list = stocks['Ticker'].tolist()
c = p.Client(api_token='TOKEN', version='stable')
timeframe = '2y'
df = c.chartDF(symbol=sym, timeframe=timeframe)[['close']]
df
```

This DataFrame contains the date and the daily closing price. Now do any of you have any ideas how to loop through my list of tickers, so that I get a comprehensive DataFrame of all the historical prices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty list to append to and concat everything together after you iterate over all the tickers

```
import pyEX as p
import pandas as pd


stock_list = stocks['Ticker'].tolist()
c = p.Client(api_token='TOKEN', version='stable')
timeframe = '2y'

dfs = []  # create an empty list
for sym in stock_list:  # iterate over your ticker list
    df = c.chartDF(symbol=sym, timeframe=timeframe)[['close']]  # create your frame
    dfs.append(df)  # append frame to list
    
final_df = pd.concat(dfs)  # concat all your frames together into one
```

## Update with Try-Except

```
import pyEX as p
import pandas as pd


stock_list = stocks['Ticker'].tolist()
c = p.Client(api_token='TOKEN', version='stable')
timeframe = '2y'

dfs = []  # create an empty list
for sym in stock_list:  # iterate over your ticker list
    try:
        df = c.chartDF(symbol=sym, timeframe=timeframe)[['close']]  # create your frame
        dfs.append(df)  # append frame to list
    except KeyError:
        print(f'KeyError for {sym}')
    
final_df = pd.concat(dfs)  # concat all your frames together into one
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried to run your code, bit it gives me the error: 
KeyError: "None of [Index(['close'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]". Do you by any chance have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What does `stock_list` look like because I did not modify how you actually create your frame using `df = c.chartDF(symbol=sym, timeframe=timeframe)[['close']] ` Test it out again but change `stock_list = stocks['Ticker'].tolist()` to `stock_list = ['AAPL']` and see if it works. It it works then one of your tickers in the list is not returning a `close` column. Lastly you probably should keep the ticker name and not just the close column `c.chartDF(symbol=sym, timeframe=timeframe)[['close', 'ticker_name_col']]` Without seeing some sample data that is returned it is going to be hard to help

Comment: That gives code executes without error. So are you saying that there might be an issue with my list of stocks? Or perhaps even the database from where I'm getting my data?

Comment: Correct, one of your ticker names might not be correct and is therefore not returning a close column which caused the error. I will update my answer with a workaround for that. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Nbs610 See update and note about adding the ticker name to your output so you know what close price is associated with each ticker symbol: `df = c.chartDF(symbol=sym, timeframe=timeframe)[['close', 'ticker_name_column']]`

Comment: I have now run the new code and it seems to be working! To some degree atleast. The code gives me a list - not a DataFrame. And the list is "minimized" such that it only shows the first observations and the latest observations for each stock. When converting the list to a DataFrame and then to a CSV-file to open in Excel, this minimization still occurs (displayed by the usual "... ..."). Do you have any fix for this?

Comment: @Nbs610 can you run the following code and update your question with some data by doing `df = c.chartDF(symbol='AAPL', timeframe='2y'); print(df.head().to_dict())`

Comment: I made the code work! Or more precisely - you made it work. Thank you very much for your time and patience.

Comment: @Nbs610 Glad it worked out for you. Good luck and happy coding.